# Repeat the values of a row in matrix N number of times

Tags: r, matrix

If I have a matrix in R that looks like the below:

```
1,3
7,1
8,2
```

How would I write code that creates a matrix like this:

```
1,3
1,3
1,3
7,1
8,2
8,2
```

Where it repeats the row based on the right .column value?  Keep in mind I have a matrix that actually has a lot more rows than 2

Comment: FYI: Your question is attracting down votes because you have simply asked for people to provide code (i.e. a solution) for you without demonstrating that you have tried or researched any solutions yourself.

Comment: Do you know how to use the `rep` function?

Comment: yes, i tried using the rep function and it works fine when i input 3,1,2 as the arguments, but I don't know how to do it without a loop. From my research, I've been trying to use the lapply function without success

Comment: What have you tired so far?

Comment: I've read in my matrix which is 1500 by 2 and I found a code online which creates a custom function rep.row<-function(x,n){matrix(rep(x,each=n),nrow=n)}.  Then I try to use it and do  matrix(rep(x,x))

Comment: I'm thinking i need to use the lapply combined with the rep function.  I'm just not sure how exactly.

Comment: @user2120963 welcome to SO  :)  to all downvoters: OP might be relatively new, but this question is not so bad..  can anyone find a duplicate?  i couldn't..

Comment: I had downvoted because the original post had the numbers in what looked like a single vector.  It was very unclear what was being asked.

Answer (score 14):

```
# construct your initial matrix
x <- matrix( c( 1 , 3 , 7 , 1 , 8 , 2 ) , 3 , 2 , byrow = TRUE )

# take the numbers 1 thru the number of rows..
1:nrow(x)

# repeat each of those elements this many times
x[ , 2 ]

# and place both of those inside the `rep` function
rows <- rep( 1:nrow(x) , x[ , 2 ] )

# ..then return exactly those rows!
x[ rows , ]

# or save into a new variable
y <- x[ rows , ]
```

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question.  After I run the line of code rows <- rep( 1:nrow(x) , x[ , 2 ] )  I get an error: Error in rep(x, each = n) : unused argument(s) (each = n)

Comment: Check my comment to my own answer, you have probably made another rep function in your R session which gets called instead of the R base library's rep function.

Comment: I really like the use of `rep` here. Element-wise vectorization, very elegant

Comment: Yes, this is much more efficient than the code in my answer. Simple benchmarking with rbenchmark package tells that my code takes about 50% more time than this.

Answer (score 8):

Here is your original matrix:

```
a<-matrix(c(1,7,8,3,1,2),3,2)
```

This makes you the first column:

```
rep(a[,1],times=a[,2])
```

And this makes you the second column:

```
rep(a[,2],times=a[,2])
```

Combine these with cbind:

```
cbind(rep(a[,1],times=a[,2]),rep(a[,2],times=a[,2]))

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    1    3
[4,]    7    1
[5,]    8    2
[6,]    8    2
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.  After I run : cbind(rep(a[,1],times=a[,2]),rep(a[,2],times=a[,2])) I get an error: Error in rep(a[, 1], times = a[, 2]) : 
  unused argument(s) (times = a[, 2])

Comment: If you run the above codes in new R session it works. You probably have some other function called rep in your session loaded as you noted in your comments to your question that you were using a custom rep function. Remove that by using command rm(rep) and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
A <- matrix( c( 1 , 3 , 7 , 1 , 8 , 2 ) , 3 , 2 , byrow = TRUE )

a<-c(3,1,2)

f<-function(i1){
 rep(A[i1,],a[i1])
}

matrix(unlist(sapply(1:3,f)),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
```